# How can I pass a list from one class to another?

Tags: python, list, class

I'm still pretty new to python so, as said in the title, I'm trying to pass a list from inside one class to another class.

For example:

```
class class_One:
  def__init__(self)
     list_wanting_to_be_passed = [1,2,3,4,5]

class class_Two:
  def __init__(self,list1):
     self.list1 = list1
     print(self.list1)

class_One()
```

As shown in the example I want a list from class one to be passed to class two so that it can then be used (printed in the example).

Comment: Do you actually mean `class_Two()` to print?

Comment: sorry @Ipounng but I'm not sure what you mean. I'm trying to use the list being passed within the class_Two for a different function, so I was trying to test it being printed.

Comment: I mean you called `class_One()` in the end, but `class_One()` does not print anything. So I guess you meant to call `class_Two()` actually.

Comment: To be clear you don't _call_ classes. You instantiate them (e.g. use the class as a template to create new objects). You then call methods of your newly created objects. `__init__` happens to be a special method which is always called right after you create a new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `list_wanting_to_be_passed` an instance attribute so that you can keep a reference to it:

```python
class ClassOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_wanting_to_be_passed = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


class ClassTwo:
    def __init__(self, list1):
        self.list1 = list1


object_one = ClassOne()
object_two = ClassTwo(object_one.list_wanting_to_be_passed)
print(object_two.list1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk, but is there any way I could print "object_two.list1" in the classTwo object? Due to I'm wanting to use this list within a function in that class.

Comment: It's up to you. You can do whatever you want with `self.list1` in any instance method of `ClassTwo`. Note that the object is only known as `object_two` **outside** the class. When you are in your class it's always `self` (actually strictly speaking it doesn't have to be `self`, but it's an accepted convention).